# Change Visibility of Controls Based Upon What Is Selected In a List View

Tags: c#, xaml, datatemplate, winui-3

I have a ListView with a bunch of people in it that supports multiple selection. I want to have it so that when a person is selected by way of the checkbox that additional controls appear - in this case a StackPanel containing some TimePicker controls becomes visible.

When the person is unselected the StackPanel should revert to being invisible.

[image]

[image]

My current code:

```
XAML:
<ContentDialog.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactListViewTemplate" x:DataType="model:Client">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Width ="32"
            Height="32"
            Margin="6"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumBrush}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{x:Bind FirstName}"
            x:Phase="1"
            Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
            Margin="12,6,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{x:Bind LastName}"
            x:Phase="2"
            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
            Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="timePanel" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <TimePicker Header="Start"></TimePicker>
            <TimePicker Header="End"></TimePicker>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ContentDialog.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="clientsList" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}" SelectionChanged="ClientsList_SelectionChanged" />
```

Code Behind:

```
private void ClientsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("called mett " + e.AddedItems.Count);
    var listView= sender as ListView;
    if(e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        
    }
    if(e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(var item in e.AddedItems)
        {
           ListViewItem myListViewItem = (ListViewItem)item;
           ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListViewItem);
            StackPanel stackPanel = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate.FindDescendant("timePanel") as StackPanel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it WPF or WinUI3? they are not the same technology

Comment: I am using WinUI 3 but I'm pretty sure is fairly similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show you one way to do this by using the `Loaded` event on your **timePanel**.

```cs
private void TimePanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not StackPanel timePanel ||
        timePanel.FindAscendant<ListView>() is not ListView listView ||
        timePanel.DataContext is not object dataContext ||
        listView.ContainerFromItem(dataContext) is not ListViewItem listViewItem)
    {
        return;
    }

    timePanel.SetBinding(
        VisibilityProperty,
        new Binding
        {
            Source = listViewItem,
            Path = new PropertyPath("IsSelected"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Converter = new TrueToVisibleConverter(),
        });
}
```

and the `TrueToVisibleConverter` should be something like this:

```cs
public class TrueToVisibleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is bool boolValue && boolValue is true
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

BTW, the `FindAscendant` extension method comes from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/dependencyobjectextensions) NuGet package.

Comment: That did the trick thanks once again :) I am also wondering how would I access the timepicker controls to extract their data? Ideally I want to at the end combine the data of the client with the data from those controls.

Comment: You need add a property fo `TimeSpan` on your **Client** and bind it with `TwoWay` mode.

Comment: The client model doesn't have any timespans, I combine Client with those TimeSpans to create another model/class/db table. 

I ended up doing this:
foreach(var item in e.AddedItems)
{
ListViewItem container = clientsList.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListViewItem;
if (container != null)
{
    StackPanel stackPanel = FindVisualChild<StackPanel>(container);
    if(stackPanel != null)
    {
        TimePicker tp1 =stackPanel.FindChild("startTime") as TimePicker;
        if(tp1 != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Time: " + tp1.Time);
        }
    }
}
}